# Unity WebGL Game's Canvas UI scale changes with windows scale

Tags: unity, html-canvas, scale, unity-ui, unity-webgl

[image: Windows Scaling Setting in display settings.]

So this is the setting that is affecting my game. My game is  a webgl build from unity running in chrome, hosted on itch.io.

At 100% windows scaling setting, the UI elements have expected size,positioning etc.
[image: 100% Scaling UI]

However at 125% windows scaling settings (which I use), everything goes off.

[image]

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this problem? That is, starting from the New Project wizard, what is the shortest sequence of actions that leads to a project that shows this kind of mismatch?

Comment: The background is simply made up of simple ground tiles which is displayed by the main camera. The clouds and sky is part of the tile grid. There is a canvas which contains a "panel" containing 28 buttons. The canvas is set to Scale with screen size, 960x540, 100 reference pixel units and Match Height or Width.

Comment: Edit your question to contain all of these steps. Keep in mind, it may be simpler to reproduce the problem in a project with fewer parts, while still getting answers that apply to your original scene as well. The more you trim down your MCVE, the easier it is for a user here to test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you. Even something as simple as "does it need to be 28 items in a grid? Is 4 enough to see the effect?" helps reduce uncertainty and shorten the critical path to a solution.